# Convert and calculate the limit and usage and then display it in a message

Tags: php, codeigniter, imap

Hi I am using imap with codeigniter. I am trying to get my imap usage and limit message just like google has on there inbox it has a percentage displayed like

`0.07 GB (0%) of 15 GB used`

Currently I can only get my one to display like

`(455112.26830953%) of 2.00 GB used`

> Question: How can I make sure I can get the imap to caculate the limit and usage correct and display it in a message.

When I echo the total size of all email `$count` the out put is 471858

```
if (isset($results)) {

    if ($order == 'DESC') {
        $lists = array_reverse($results);
    }

    $count = 0; 

    foreach ($lists as $overview) {
        $count += $overview->size;

        if (isset($overview->subject)) {
            echo $overview->msgno ." ". $overview->date ." ". $overview->from ." ". $overview->subject . "<br/>"; 
        } else {
            echo $overview->msgno ." ". $overview->date ." ". $overview->from ." ". "No Subject<br/>";
        }
    }

    // returns the total email sizes
    echo $count;

    echo "<br/><br/>";

    $quota = imap_get_quotaroot($mbox, "INBOX");

    $message = $quota['MESSAGE'];

    $percentage = ($message['limit'] / $count) * 100;

    echo "(" . $percentage . "%) of " . $this->byte_convert($message['limit']) . " used";
}

function byte_convert($size) {
    # size smaller then 1kb
    if ($size < 1024) return $size . ' Byte';
    # size smaller then 1mb
    if ($size < 1048576) return sprintf("%4.2f KB", $size/1024);
    # size smaller then 1gb
    if ($size < 1073741824) return sprintf("%4.2f MB", $size/1048576);
    # size smaller then 1tb
    if ($size < 1099511627776) return sprintf("%4.2f GB", $size/1073741824);
    # size larger then 1tb
    else return sprintf("%4.2f TB", $size/1073741824);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is backward. You need to divide `$count` by `$message['limit']` instead of the other way around:

```
// 2 GB = 2147483648 bytes

$percentage = ($message['limit'] / $count) * 100;
// (2147483648 / 471858) * 100 = 455112% = incorrect

$percentage = ($count / $message['limit']) * 100;
// (471858 / 2147483648) * 100 = 0.02% = correct
```

Then you can just add `$this->byte_convert($count)` to your output to get the same display as in Gmail:

```
echo $this->byte_convert($count) . " (" . $percentage . "%) of " . $this->byte_convert($message['limit']) . " used";
// 460.80 KB (0.02%) of 2.00 GB used
```

Comment: It produces this now `460.80 KB (0.021972600380877%) of 2.00 GB used` why does the google one show `(0%)` is theirs incorrect?

Comment: No, they probably just round it down to 0 decimals.

Comment: Sure, just use `round($percentage)`.

Comment: Ok now I just have to `$this->byte_convert($count)` to the GB instead of KB I will try and figure it out.

Comment: Yeah if Google is showing 0.07 GB, that's because their 15 GB limit is not just your mail but also [includes Drive and Photos](https://drive.googleblog.com/2013/05/bringing-it-all-together-15-gb-now.html)